# Sci-fi puzzle/game book involving an alien world/planet

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel, puzzle

I'm looking for a book I remember loving as a child.  I borrowed it from the library several times, I believe between 2000 and 2009, but I imagine it was published a while before this.

It was an A4 (I think), full-colour puzzle/game book set in an alien world/planet. There was a running story, I think, but I can't remember the plot. On each page there were activities to do to progress the story. I don't remember much but I think some might have been finding a certain amount of the right food.  The puzzles and storyline were relatively complex as I remember. I think it would have been designed for older children/early teens. The images were very detailed and had great art.

Any ideas of what to look for would be amazing, thank you! Also it's not *Puzzle Planet* or *The Planet of Terror*.

Comment: You could check out the Usborne Puzzle book series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usborne_Puzzle_Adventure_series, these are a range of books with a plot and a puzzle to solve on each page. The only one that I can think of that takes place on another planet/s is The Intergalactic Bus Trip.

Comment: Thank you! It's not one of these but I had totally forgotten about them so it was great to rediscover them too